# How to manipulate .dbf files using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, odbc, dbf

I am trying to something like this:

```
        string pathFiles = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "DB");
        string strconn = "Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};DriverID=277;" +
               "Dbq="+pathFiles+";";                      
        OdbcConnection odbconn = new OdbcConnection(strconn);
        odbconn.Open();
```

and i get this exception

```
ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

The problem is that the same code runs ok on windiws XP , visual studio 2010, office 2007 and it doesn't work on windows 7 64bit , visual studio 2008,office 2010.
I really don't know whatvis the difference, i am new to win 7.
Some tips would be great.Thanks.

Comment: Is the Windows 7 machine 64 bits?

Comment: yes, windows 7 is 64 bit

Comment: To follow up w/ Mike's comment you might check and see if you get different behavior if you set your projects target platorm build settings from Any CPU to x86.  There are certain db drivers that don't exist in a 64 bit platform.

Comment: yep, that was the problem , i changed the platform target to x86 and it works but i am wondering if it is the best way to do it.

Comment: We have a lot of products that are deployed this way because of dependencies in the project like drivers that don't exist / install on 64bit.  For us it is the best way to accomplish the task until we have time to replace those dependencies with something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it is worth, I manipulate dBase files using the following connection on Vista and Windows 7.  I still set the target output as x86.

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;" +
    "Data Source={0};Extended Properties=dBase IV;", Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, OutputFolderName))))
{
    //....
    //....
}
```

The output folder name is just the directory where the DBase files that I'm either writing to or reading from.